# Keep parent with children open when linking to new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, joomla2.5

I have a vertical accordion menu that opens on hover, stays open and closes when other items are hovered. I had great help from @JDandChips on getting this working.

What I really need now though is to be able to select a particular menu item (virtual-tour) to open the nested list. Then when navigating through each link in this nested list it loads a new page (already does this as it's Joomla!) and the nested list stays open on these pages only. Then when another link is clicked it closed again. Here's what I have working...

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
 $("ul.menu-main > li").hover(function () {

    //Don't do this again if the same menu is hovered
    if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        //Ensure any open sub-menu is closed.
        $("li.selected").children("ul").stop(true, true).slideUp(1000);
        $("li.selected").removeClass('selected');
        //Open sub-menu
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(this).children("ul").slideDown(1000);
    }
 });
 });
 </script>

<nav>

<ul class="menu-main">
<li class="item-108"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class="item-111 deeper parent"><a href="#">History and Restoration</a>
<ul>
<li class="item-125"><a href="#">History</a></li>
<li class="item-126"><a href="#">The Connection</a></li>
<li class="item-127"><a href="#">Previous Residents</a></li>
<li class="item-128"><a href="#">Restoration</a></li>
<li class="item-129"><a href="#">Sidmouth / Heritage Coast</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="item-112"><a href="#">Wedding Venue</a></li>
<li class="item-113"><a href="#">Hiring Rooms</a>       </li>
<li class="item-114 deeper parent"><a href="#/virtual-tour"     >Virtual Tour</a><ul><li class="item-132"><a href="#/virtual-tour/entrance-hall" >Entrance Hall</a></li>
<li class="item-133"><a href="#/virtual-tour/amyatt-room-one" >Amyatt Room One</a></li>
<li class="item-134"><a href="#/virtual-tour/amyatt-room-two" >Amyatt Room Two</a></li>
<li class="item-135"><a href="#/virtual-tour/board-room" >Board Room</a></li><li class="item-136"><a href="#/virtual-tour/captain-phillips-room" >Captain Phillips Room</a></li>
<li class="item-137"><a href="#/virtual-tour/function-room" >Function Room</a></li>
<li class="item-138"><a href="#/virtual-tour/gordon-langford-room" >Gordon Langford Room</a></li>
<li class="item-139"><a href="#/virtual-tour/hatton-wood-room" >Hatton Wood Room</a></li>
<li class="item-140"><a href="#/virtual-tour/meeting-room" >Meeting Room</a></li>
<li class="item-141"><a href="#/virtual-tour/rw-sampson-room" >RW Sampson Room</a></li>
<li class="item-142"><a href="#/virtual-tour/first-floor-reception-hallway" >First Floor Reception Hallway</a></li></ul></li>
<li class="item-115"><a href="#">Art and Exhibitions</a></li>
<li class="item-116"><a href="#">Learning</a></li>
<li class="item-117 deeper parent"><a href="#">How Can I help</a>
<ul>
<li class="item-130"><a href="#">Friends of Kennaway House</a></li>
<li class="item-131"><a href="#">Volunteer Opportunities</a></li></ul></li>
<li class="item-118"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
<li class="item-119"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>


</nav><!-- #nav -->

nav {
position:absolute;
top:190px;
left:0;
width:200px;
min-width:200px;
height:900px;
background:transparent;
z-index:9999;
}

#nav-bg {
position:absolute;
top:200px;
left:0;
width:200px;
height:80%;
background:<?php echo $contactscheme ?>;
}

nav:before {
content:'';
position:absolute;
top:-10px;
right:0;
width:0;
border-top:10px solid transparent; /* height of right point */
border-right:200px solid #570C2A;
z-index:2;
}

nav:after {
content:'';
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:135px;
width:50px;
height:500px;
background:transparent;
-webkit-transform:rotate(2deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(2deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(2deg);
transform:rotate(2deg);
-webkit-box-shadow:<?php echo $boxshadownav ?>;
-moz-box-shadow:<?php echo $boxshadownav ?>;
box-shadow:<?php echo $boxshadownav ?>;
z-index:-1;
}

.menu-main,
.menu-main ul {
max-height:900px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
text-align:center;
font-size:1.2em;
background:#570C2A;
}

.menu-main li {
line-height:70px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
   }

.menu-main a {
display:block;
color:beige;
text-decoration:none;
    }

.menu-main a:hover, a:focus {
color:darkslategray;
 text-decoration:none;
text-shadow:none;
outline:0 none;
-webkit-transition:250ms linear 0s;
-moz-transition:250ms linear 0s;
-o-transition:250ms linear 0s;
transition:250ms linear 0s;
}

.menu-main a:hover, a:focus {
color:beige;
text-shadow:1px -1px 14px beige;
}

.menu-main ul {
height:auto;
display:none;
}

.menu-main ul li {
font-size:0.6em;
line-height:30px;
}

.menu-main ul a {
background:transparent;
}

li.item-111.parent {
background:#486060;
line-height:22px;
padding:12px 3%;
}

/* -- sub menu styles for History and Restoration  -- */
.item-125, .item-126, .item-127, .item-128, .item-129 {
background:#486060;
}

.item-125 {
border-top:2px dotted <?php echo $listborders ?>;
}

.item-129 {
    border-bottom:2px dotted <?php echo $listborders ?>;
}

/* -- ===end=== -- */

.item-112 {
background:#557171;
}

.item-113 {
background:#663366;
}

.item-114 {
background:#86ACA8;
}

.item-115 {
background:#CD7F72;
}

.item-116 {
background:#BD8A16;
}

li.item-117.parent {
background:#C59F92;
line-height:50px;
padding:12px 3%;
}

/* -- sub menu styles for How Can I Help -- */
.item-130, .item-131 {
background:#C59F92;
}

.item-130 {
border-top:2px dotted <?php echo $listborders ?>;
}

.item-131 {
border-bottom:2px dotted <?php echo $listborders ?>;
}

/* -- ===end=== -- */

.item-118 {
background:#869175;
}

.item-119 {
background:<?php echo $contactscheme ?>;
}
```

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly, you will need to set a cookie when a section is set to the "open" state.  When the page loads, you will need to check the cookie to determine which section needs to be set to open.  However, it would probably be better to set the menu's initial state through PHP.

Comment: I was trying to avoid cookies and php, I was wondering if you could select the url to know when to keep it open or if there was a way to addClass to that menu to keep it open when the parent is opened...

Comment: But you're already using PHP (*points to Joomla2.5 tag*)...  If your directory structure matches your menu hierarchy, then you can perform matches on the URL via JS.

Comment: Yes, I realise I'm using php with Joomla! but I am looking to enhance the menu that's already created with Javascript rather than re-create it in php. So you think it's possible to match the url in this scenario? To make it easier I guess all the sub menus need this function.

As it's already targeted with ul.menu-main > li is it possible to manipulate this?

Comment: Really hoping someone can help with this I'm struggling to implement this final piece of the puzzle...

Comment: @JDandChips I don't suppose you have a solution to this do you... I'm really struggling with this one...!

Comment: Is there anyone who can shed light on this predicament for me I have tried all sorts and can't seem to get this to work... It's just completely baffling me to get the menu to stay open on a new page load... Any more help would be great on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may notice that after you click an item in the menu, that menu item will load with the class "active". You can then target this menu item via active and show the item.

Here is the code:

```
if($('.active.parent > ul').length > 0)
{
    $('.active.parent > ul').show();
}
```

The first line just checks that there is an active element, otherwise we might get a script error. Within the bracers the code simply shows the element. Give this a go and let me know how you get on.

Also, it's a good idea to utilize your developer toolbar (F12) in cases like this, so you can monitor the DOM and spot things like the active class.

Comment: I have the same problem but this solution didn't work for me, could you please take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018811/menu-dropdown-expand-children-if-parent-is-active