# Keep navigation open when new page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css, joomla2.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keep parent with children open when linking to new page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494387/keep-parent-with-children-open-when-linking-to-new-page)

I have this code which is controlling an accordion menu... I have asked this before but to no avail so thought I might simplify my question...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
 $("ul.menu-main > li").hover(function () {
    //Don't do this again if the same menu is hovered
    if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        //Ensure any open sub-menu is closed.
        $("li.selected").children("ul").stop(true, true).slideUp(1000);
        $("li.selected").removeClass('selected');
        //Open sub-menu
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(this).children("ul").slideDown(1000);
    }
});
});
</script>
```

I am looking to find a way of keeping it open when a menu item is selected the sub menu stays open when navigating the sub menu items only. Maybe some kind of 'find current url'? I can explain more if needed it's a bit rambly...

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to store (a list of) the open menus in a cookie, localStorage or sessionStorage. Be advised that only the cookie method will be widely supported.

But, the basic idea will be to store the open menus as they are opened (and remove them from the list when closed). Then when the page loads, look for that list of open menus and if present, use that list to manually (programatically) open then again upon page load.

Hope this helps.