# Remember menu state on reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a navigation menu with the exact same functionality as the one on this site: http://www.rex-ny.com/

I would prefer to do it only using HTML and CSS, but I tried all day and couldn't find a solution.

1. When I select a menu item, I want that menu to stay open after the page loads. Is this possible?
2. I want to also make the Main menu items clickable, so that they load a new page AND when that page loads that menu is open.

Here is what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/MEL9d/

Here is the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu > li > a').click(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
            $('#menu li ul').hide();
            $(this).next().toggle();
            $('#menu li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

And CSS:

```
#menu {
    float: left;
}
#menu li a {
    display: block;
}
#menu li ul {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This sounds impossible without using localStorage (HTML5) or a server language. Remember a browser is stateless so it will NOT remember these things without server/storage help.

Comment: Use cookies or [`localstorage`](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

Comment: It's not impossible... You could just add a class to the body on each page and an id on each menu item, and then style that in CSS, `.home #home, .page #page { color: red; }`

Comment: You can also use ajax to load pages without having to refresh page - [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494387/keep-parent-with-children-open-when-linking-to-new-page

Comment: @elclanrs That sounds like a simple approach but I'm still not quite sure how to go about it. I'm pretty new at this. Can you elaborate a bit? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this is plain HTML and CSS. Assuming you have a structure like this:

```
- site
  + css
  + js
    index.html
    about.html
```

You can add a class to the body of each page, so `index` for `index.php` and `about` for `about.php`:

```
<body class="about">
```

Then in your menu, add an id (or a class if you plan on having the menu in many places) to each item that corresponds to the page:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li id="index" class="active"><a href="index.html"></li>
  <li id="about"><a href="about.html"></li>
</ul>
```

Finally, using CSS you can style the menu items for each page specifically:

```
.index #index,
.about #about,
#menu .active {
  // styles for active item
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this lead me in the right direction. I used .index #index > ul {} and didn't need the class="active" tag

Comment: Any idea why this isn't working for me in Internet Explorer? Here's the website http://jaws.ac/.. Notice how the menu doesn't open in IE. Does it have to do with the hierarchy?